# Why does my python program not run when I double click the .sh file

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu

Device: Jetson Nano developer kit 2GB

I've got a python program that I want to launch by double clicking. The reason for this is because I want to control the entire device with just a touchscreen. I've written a `.sh` file to launch the python program however when I double click it a terminal opens and immediately closes, the same thing happens when I run the `.sh` file manually through the terminal.

`.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting"
sleep 1
cd /home/velotech/workspace
python3 detect.py
```

The weird thing is that when I run the command `python3 detect.py` manually from the terminal the program runs just fine.
Things I've tried:

1. Made a simple `hello.py` program, this one works both by double clicking the `.sh` file and through terminal so I don't think it has to do with my .sh file

```
print('Enter your name:')
x = input()
print('Hello, ' + x)
```

2. Added print statements in my python program, I've found out that the program stops working after I import two jetson libraries `Jetson.inference` and `jetson.utils`.
   A snippet of the code from `detect.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import serial
from gpsZEDF9P.ublox_gps import UbloxGps
import time
import threading as thread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QSizePolicy, QComboBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
print("this gets printed")
import jetson.utils
import jetson.inference
print("This does not")
... rest of the code
```

When I run this from the terminal it works but when I run it through the `.sh` file it closes the terminal after the first print statement. So my question is, what could this be?

Comment: Have you tried running the `.sh` file from your terminal? Should show errors

Comment: If I had to guess, you're using another environment (maybe venv or something like that) when you're running it from the terminal. The import fails because this package isn't installed system-wide. But again, just a guess. See what @mousetail suggested

Comment: I have tried running it manually in the terminal, it does not give any errors. At least it doesn't show any

Comment: but to clarify, it still opens and closes a terminal immediately

Comment: If you set the terminal to stay open after the command finishes, you can look at the output there

Comment: How do I do that? I do not see any text appear, not even for a split second so I don't know if any will appear if the terminal stays open longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, after I updated the libraries Jetson Utils and Jetson Inference it threw a warning saying jetson.utils and jetson.inference were deprecated and to use jetson_utils and jetson_inference instead. After doing so I was able to run the program from a .sh file and by double clicking it

Answer (score 0):

You are running:

```
python3 detect.py
```

Debug by running this instead:

```
python3 -m site
sleep 30
```

Verify that the identical `$PYTHONPATH` / `sys.path`
is used in both your terminal and double-click environments.
Take care to `export` a new value for that env var
if you notice a mismatch,
or use `conda activate myproject`
or the corresponding `venv` command,
so the same libraries are available in both environments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've used `python3 -m site` in the .sh file and manually through the terminal, the results are identical. If you want them I can share them but there aren't enough characters available in a comment.

Comment: Hmmm, I had been betting on `ModuleNotFoundError`, no such luck, ok. Definitely use that `sleep 30` with your real code, so you can read any stack trace it might produce. Verify within the terminal that `/usr/bin/python3 detect.py` and `./detect.sh` both run as desired. Now use standard debugging techniques. Just before the initial import of serial, insert a `breakpoint()` line. Use `l` list and `n` next commands to see how far you get before fail. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs

Comment: Well, thats the thing running ./detect.sh in the terminal also does not work